# Unexpected results when casting dword to byte [4] (endianity swap?)

Tags: c++, casting, endianness, dword

Im trying to cast a dword into an array of 4 bytes.
When i do this, the bytes seem to flip around (change endianness)

As i understand it a dword equaling 0x11223344 on little endian systems will look like this:
**0000_1011___0001_0110___0010_0001____0010_1100**

but when i do this:

```
typedef unsigned long dword;
typedef unsigned char byte;
int main(void)
{
    dword a = 0x11223344;
    byte b[4];
    memcpy(b, &a, 4);
    printf("%x %x %x %x\n", b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3]);
}
```

I get **44 33 22 11**.
I expected it to be **11 22 33 44**.
The same thing happens when i use reinterpret_cast or

```
union
{
dword a;
byte b[4];
} foo;
```

Im guessing Im wrong and not the compiler/processor, but what am i missing here?
Also how would this look on a big endian system?

Edit:
So i guess my understanding of little endian systems was wrong.
Another question: which would be faster while still being portable: using shifts to get the individual byte values or using memcpy/reinterpret_cast and then htonl()/ntohl()?

Comment: Numbers are stored starting from the little end (the least significant end) on little-endian systems.

Comment: You didn't even read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness, did you? Apart from that, while converting to binary, you treated the hexadecimal number as if it was byte-wise decimal...

Comment: short answer: don't do this. either assemble the value yourself from the raw bytes using proper shifts, or use a runtime function like `ntols()` (note: not standard-lib provided).

Comment: which is faster, shifts or memcpy/reinterpret_cast with ntols();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your understanding of little-endian is incorrect. Little endian means that the least significant byte is at the lowest memory address.

Also:

> As i understand it a dword equaling 0x11223344 on little endian systems will look like this:
>
> `0000 1011 0001 0110 0010 0001 0010 1100`

That bit pattern doesn't have anything to do with `0x11223344` at all, be it little or big endian. On a little endian architecture, it would read

```
0100 0100 0011 0011 0010 0010 0001 0001
```

On a big endian system, however, the same would be

```
0001 0001 0010 0010 0011 0011 0100 0100
```

Comment: whoops i converted them from the decimal 11 22 33 44 to binary accidentally. But this does make sense now. I always thought that little endian was the other way around. Big endian is the more 'normal' style, like we write numbers right?

Comment: @user2712404 Both are perfectly normal.

Comment: It maybe helpful to think of the actual interpretation of the number.  I.E. if I have 0x0001 dollars.  Depending on the endianness I may be eating noodles or I may be eating 256.00 dollar surf n turf.

Comment: @user2712404 - little endian is the more "normal" style when you add and subtract numbers. Calculate `6174 + 5597` with pencil and paper.